# How to upload image to phpmyadmin database and save it to a specific username

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to upload image to phpmyadmin database and save to a specific username. After that, I want to retrieve that image and display it in the html page. I am currently using jquery , ajax , php , javascript. Being a newbie, i am trying to do it in the simplest way possible. Thanks!

I have tried many youtube tutorials but its hot helping much

After the image has been uploaded from the html page, it should be successfully saved in the database and alse retrieve from there to display the uploaded image in the html page

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer, For those who are looking for the same thing here is how I did it. You should not consider uploading images to the database instead you can store the name of the uploaded file in your database and then retrieve the file name and use it where ever you want to display the image.

**HTML CODE**

```
<input type="file" name="imageUpload" id="imageUpload">
```

**PHP CODE**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //Process the image that is uploaded by the user

    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }

    $image=basename( $_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"],".jpg"); // used to store the filename in a variable

    //storind the data in your database
    $query= "INSERT INTO items VALUES ('$id','$title','$description','$price','$value','$contact','$image')";
    mysql_query($query);

    require('heading.php');
    echo "Your add has been submited, you will be redirected to your account page in 3 seconds....";
    header( "Refresh:3; url=account.php", true, 303);
}
```

**CODE TO DISPLAY THE IMAGE**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><img src='uploads/$row[6].jpg' height='150px' width='300px'></td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

**OR OTHER EXAMPLE**

MySQL has a BLOB (binary large object) data type that can hold a large amount of binary data. The BLOB data type is perfect for storing the image data. In MySQL, four BLOB types are available – **TINYBLOB**, **BLOB**, **MEDIUMBLOB**, and **LONGBLOB**.

To store the image data a table needs to be created in the database.

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `image` longblob NOT NULL,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The following HTML form allows users to choose the image file to upload.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="image"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Store Image in Database **(upload.php)**

The `upload.php` file contains the following functionalities.

- Check whether the user selects an image file to upload.
- Retrieve the content of image file by the `tmp_name`.
- Create the connection to MySQL database and select the database.
- Insert the binary content of the image in the `images` table.
- Show the image uploading status to the user.

Code for insert image into database

```
<?php
      if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
          $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
          if($check !== false){
              $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
              $imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));

            /*
             * Insert image data into database
             */

            //DB details
            $dbHost     = 'localhost';
            $dbUsername = 'root';
            $dbPassword = '*****';
            $dbName     = 'codexworld';

            //Create connection and select DB
            $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

            // Check connection
            if($db->connect_error){
                die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
            }

            $dataTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            //Insert image content into database
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT into images (image, created) VALUES ('$imgContent', '$dataTime')");
            if($insert){
                echo "File uploaded successfully.";
            }else{
                echo "File upload failed, please try again.";
            } 
        }else{
            echo "Please select an image file to upload.";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Retrieve image from database **(view.php)**

In this file, we will retrieve the image content from the MySQL database based on the ID and display on the web page. To render image file in the web page, the **Content-type** header is used.

```
  <?php
  if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
      //DB details
     $dbHost     = 'localhost';
     $dbUsername = 'root';
     $dbPassword = '*****';
     $dbName     = 'codexworld';

     //Create connection and select DB
     $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

     //Check connection
     if($db->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
     }

     //Get image data from database
     $result = $db->query("SELECT image FROM images WHERE id = {$_GET['id']}");

     if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $imgData = $result->fetch_assoc();

        //Render image
        header("Content-type: image/jpg"); 
        echo $imgData['image']; 
    }else{
        echo 'Image not found...';
    }
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: This does not work for me.